# Save file in physical location of an orchard cms module

Tags: orchardcms

I'm developing an orchard module using visual studio 2013. I want to create a folder in my module folder, and create a text file in this folder.
I tried to get the physical path of my module in this way:

```
var areaName = HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.DataTokens["area"] as string;
var myFolderPath =
                HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Modules/" + areaName + "/myFolder/");
Directory.CreateDirectory(myFolderPath);
```

But the value of mapped path in `myFolderPath` is `C:\Users\myName\Documents\My Web Sites\Orchard.Web-Site\Modules\xxxArea\myFolder` which is not the path of my orchard solution.
How can I get the physical location of my module correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely want `HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Modules/" + areaName + "/myFolder/");`Notice the tilde character at the beginning which makes it look at the root of your site.

Comment: Thanks @David. It was my negligent!